# Merging CSV data into TopoJSON file

Tags: csv, attribute-joins, topojson

I have a file, `Council_Districts.topojson`, with the following structure:

```
{ type: 'Topology', arcs: [...], transform: {...}, objects: {
  Council_Districts_2016: {
    type: 'GeometryCollection',
    geometries: [
      {
        arcs: [...],
        type: '...',
        properties: {
          'DISTRICT': 0,
          'ID': 0,
          'OBJECTID': 0,
        }
      },
      ...
    ]    
  }
}
```

I also have a `Sample_Data.csv' file with the following structure:

```
DISTRICT, varA, varB, ....,
0, .1, .2, ...
```

I'm looking to combine these two files such that my output file has the following structure:

```
{ type: 'Topology', arcs: [...], transform: {...}, objects: {
  Council_Districts_2016: {
    type: 'GeometryCollection',
    geometries: [
      {
        arcs: [...],
        type: '...',
        properties: {
          'DISTRICT': 0,
          'ID': 0,
          'OBJECTID': 0,
          'varA': .1,
          'varB': .2,
        }
      },
      ...
    ]
  }    
}
```

Googling around, I'm finding the previous answer has been to use the [external properties](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-1.x-api-reference/blob/master/Command-Line-Reference.md#user-content-external-properties) flag on the topojson cli, e.g. `topojson -e blah`, but this flag does not seem to be available within the current topojson 2.0

Comment: I also cannot find the flag in the new API

Comment: perhaps like: https://observablehq.com/@caglarkoylu/attribute-join-by-linking-topojson-with-csv-files

Comment: Similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444261/how-to-add-properties-to-topojson-file There, I have just posted an answer based on the [command-line cartography](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-2-c3a82c5c0f3) tools.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the great [mapshaper cli](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference). The join command is something like

```bsh
mapshaper input.topojson -join "input.csv" keys=DISTRICT -o output.geojson
```

Answer (score 0):

Use QGIS to convert your CSV to GeoJSON then upload your GeoJSON to [MapShaper.org](http://mapshaper.org) or [geojson.io](http://geojson.io) and download as other formats they support, like TopoJSON.

Comment: He's asking how to join a CSV file to an existing topojson, not how to create a topojson.